# parsererror Error: jQuery was not called using jsonp

Tags: jquery

I know this was asked many times in SO but using those answers didn't solve mine.

Script below:

```
$(document).on('submit','.stack_survey_form',function(e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();    

        var form = $(this);

        setPhoneAndAddress(form);

        if(form.attr('action') != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: "application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
                data: form.serialize(),
                error: function (jqXHR, text, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR + " " + text + " " + errorThrown);
                    form.attr('data-sent','true').data('sent','true');
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log('SUCCESS');
                    form.attr('data-sent','true').data('sent','true');
                    submitForm();
                }
            });
            console.log('SENT');
        }else {
            console.log('SKIP');
        }

});
```

HTML Form:

```
<form method="get" name="hostedform" class="stack_survey_form" enctype="text" action="http://myurl.com/sendData/">
 //some content here
</form>
```

> Update

Response:

```
{"status":"lead_received","message":"Lead received for processing","lead_id":4177110}
```

Comment: If there is a parserror then most likely response is not jsonp. Do you control the api endpoint? Not much information given here to work from. Also note that `serialize()` does not generate json either but at the same time there is no contentType for a GET

Comment: thanks @charlietfl, I'll try that in api.

Comment: @charlietfl, I added the response in my post can you have a look?

Comment: that's json not jsonp....big difference. If you are trying to make a cross domain call and that's why you are using jsonp, the api has to support that type

Comment: response is clearly JSON so why are you asking it for JSONP?

Comment: Yeah exactly. but I have no control on the api. this code was just passed to me by the original dev. hmmmm. now I changed the type to json and it gives me `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: this is the line that producing the error. `xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );`. I guess I don't have permission or something

Comment: Not all api's are ajax accessible. When they aren't you need to use a proxy either on a server you control or through a third party service

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for your time man. I'll search about the solution you suggested.